# Integration by parts in the definition of weak partial derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

I'm trying to understand the definition of *weak derivatives*. In many textbooks, usually the ordinary derivative version is presented as an illustration. However, once moving on to the partial derivatives, the following definition is directly given.

> If $u$ and $v$ are locally integrable functions on a nonempty open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that, for every $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$,
> $$\int_{\Omega}u \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_j} dx =-\int_\Omega v\varphi dx,$$
> then $v$ is said to be the *weak $j$-th partial derivative* of function $u$.

My understanding is, if we further assume $u\in C_0^1(\Omega)$, then we have, by Fubini's theorem,
$$\int_{\Omega}u \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_j} dx =\int_{\Omega^j}d \sigma^j \int_{\text{slice of }\Omega \text{ on } x_j}u \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_j} dx_j.$$
But then we need 3 more results: 1) since $\Omega$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, every slice is also open in $\mathbb{R}$; 2) every nonempty open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of open intervals; 3) $u\to 0$ when $x_j$ approaches every end point of these open intervals, while the values of other $x_i$'s are fixed. Only then, can we carry out the integration by parts and arrive at
$$\int_{\Omega}u \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_j} dx =-\int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j} \varphi dx,$$
which is consistent with the definition above.

> **Question:** Do we absolutely need those 3 results while doing the integration by parts? Or is it overkill?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You more or less sketched the proof of the divergence theorem without boundary, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Proofs
The divergence theorem states for $f\in C^1(\overline{\Omega},\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\Omega$ having $C^1$-boundary, that
$$\int_\Omega \operatorname{div}f\, dx = \int_{\partial\Omega}f\cdot\nu\, dA$$
and $\nu$ is the outer unit normal of $\Omega$. In dimension $1$, this is the fundamental Theorem.
If you now put $f_i = uv$ and $f_j=0$ for $i\neq j$, you obtain
$$\operatorname{div}f = \partial_iu v + u\partial_iv,$$
which by divergence theorem leads to
$$\int_\Omega u\partial_i v\, dx = -\int_{\Omega}\partial_i uv\, dx,$$
if $u,v\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ and one of them has compact support in $\Omega$ (hence the boundary term disappears). This formula is also called partial integration and is the reason for the definition of weak derivates.
So to answer your original question: You more or less have to do what you did to obtain the result in the smooth case. It just has already been done in the divergence theorem.

Edit:
You can simplify your proof a bit and only really need Fubini: Since $\varphi$ has compact support, you can without loss of generality assume $u$ and $\varphi$ are smoothly extended by zero outside of $\Omega$. Then you can work on $]-R,R[^n$ instead of $\Omega$ for a big enough $R>0$ and do the same calculations you did.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking maybe divergence theorem is relevant. But I'm worried I can't assume smoothness of the boundary. So I went to that real-analytic direction. But yes, extend $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ simplifies everything!! (But since we don't know whether $\Omega$ is bounded, it seems we have to extend it to the whole space.)

Comment: @ user760: You do not have to go to the whole space. Since $\varphi$ has compact support, you have $\varphi(x)=0$ for $x\notin B_R(0)$ for some finite $R>0$. Then you can work on that Ball (which by the way has smooth boundary). Divergence theorem also usually needs bounded $\Omega$ for integrability.